# Find all permutations of Ruby array of arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have the following input array of arrays:

```
[[1],[2,3],[4,5],[6]]
```

I'd like to produce all permutations like this:

```
[[1,2,4,6],[1,2,5,6],[1,3,4,6],[1,3,5,6]]
```

What's a nice Ruby way of doing this? Or really *any* way of doing this? I feel like there's an elegant solution that I can't see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is the cartesian product. Something like:

`[1].product([2,3],[4,5],[6]) # => [[1, 2, 4, 6], [1, 2, 5, 6], [1, 3, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 6]]`

Comment: So how does one generalize this? Let's say my initial array is `arr`... is this `arr[0].product(arr[1..-1])` or something? (It's not, I've tried it :))

Comment: Almost - you need to splat the arguments to product, as in `arr[0].product(*arr[1..-1])`